# react form hook nested controller name not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-forms

```js
interface FormInputs {
  config: Config;
}

const {
      control,
      handleSubmit,
      watch,
      setValue,
      getValues,
    } = useForm<FormInputs>();

setValue('config', config);

<Controller
            name="daoConfig.test"
            control={control}
            defaultValue={''}
            render={({ field: { onChange, value }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
              <InputField
                label=""
                onInputChange={onChange}
                value={value.toString()}
                height="46px"
                width={window.innerWidth > 700 ? '50%' : '100%'}
                placeholder={'350s'}
              />
            )}
          />
```

The problem: The above code doesn't put the `daoConfig.test` value in the html's input field.

If I do

```
  console.log(getValues('config'), ' test1')

  console.log(getValues('config.test'), ' test2')
```

They both print the correct values.

Comment: Did you find the solution?